# R - Reading text in a file and appending it to another

Tags: r, append

I am running RStudio 3.2.3 on Windows 7. I need to read certain text in a text file. The code below successfully appends from line 1 to 24 in the original file to the new file. The lines I need to append into the new file always starts with "DATE ACQUIRED = ". Can I search for that line (line 23), just read the date on it, and append the date to the file? If I could append it to a spreadsheet that would be great.

```
con <- file("LC80140332015238LGN00_MTL.txt") 
        x <- readLines(con,24) 
        unlink("data") 
        write(x,file="myMTLfile2.txt",append=TRUE)[/CODE]
```

Comment: What is the format of the date? Can you provide a chunk of LC80140332015238LGN00_MTL.txt?

Comment: Lines 10 to 21: 
  
GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA   
DATA_TYPE = "L1T"   
ELEVATION_SOURCE = "GLS2000"   
OUTPUT_FORMAT = "GEOTIFF"   
SPACECRAFT_ID = "LANDSAT_8"   
SENSOR_ID = "OLI_TIRS"   
WRS_PATH = 14   
WRS_ROW = 33   
NADIR_OFFNADIR = "NADIR"   
TARGET_WRS_PATH = 14   
TARGET_WRS_ROW = 33   
DATE_ACQUIRED = 2015-08-26   
SCENE_CENTER_TIME = "15:40:03.5512487Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple parsing using `grep` and `sub` should work just fine

```
lines <- readLines("LC80140332015238LGN00_MTL.txt")
# get lines with DATE_ACQUIRED
matched_lines <- lines[which(grepl("DATE_ACQUIRED", lines))]
# extract date
date_acquired <- sub(".*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*", "\\1", matched_lines)
write(date_acquired, "myMTLfile2.txt", append=TRUE)
```

You might need to change the regex for date parsing if you have dates in different formats.

Comment: I am still confused because sub() is for replacement. I ran the code and RStudio returned "object x not found". I think 'x' would be the replacement variable. I don't see a need to replace text; I don't see why I need to declare a variable 'x'. I just need to copy the date and append it to a new file.

Comment: I copied the wrong line to the answer. Fixed it now. `sub` is used to replace the string with just a date, in this case - extract the date.